# A case where something could bind to a non-const ref but not to a const ref?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, signature

#### Minimal question

Please consider the following functions:

```
class NonTrivialClass { /* ... */ };

void f1(NonTrivialClass      &) {}
void f2(NonTrivialClass const&) {}
```

Is there an expression invoking `f1` in which one could not replace `f1` with `f2`?

#### Context

In the prospect of a job offering, I've been asked *"to write the method `double approx(vector<Point>& pts)`"* (`Point` being given) which uses points from `pts` to approximate a known constant in a Buffon-like way.

I have written an implementation defining `double approx(vector<Point> const& pts)` (note the `const`). And for a reason yet to determine, I've failed the test!

After removing all possible explanation, I'm left with doubts about the test platform and that gripping `const` qualifier... Is it possible that their test program would have worked with `double approx(vector<Point>& pts)` but not with `double approx(vector<Point> const& pts)`?

Comment: If you see a test with `vector` instead of `std::vector` in a parameter list, maybe you should not trust it . ;)

Comment: Could it be that the test uses its function signature, which it expects you to implement? If so, you're out of luck. But you don't want to work there anyway :-)

Comment: Should have mentioned, there was a big `using namespace std;` at the start of the skeleton answer. But let us not diverge.

Comment: I finally get an answer from the test writter. In fact, the code I did input  was inserted verbatim in the test program, as an `#include "contestant_code.cc"` would. And in the skeleton answer was a starting `using namespace std;`, which I removed... The test program was expecting `vector<Point>` to compile; it did not anymore. => Test failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question admits insane answers:

```
struct NonTrivialClass {};
struct NonTrivialClass2 {
    operator NonTrivialClass&();
    operator NonTrivialClass const&();
};

void f1(NonTrivialClass      &) {}
void f2(NonTrivialClass const&) {}

int main()
{
  NonTrivialClass2 foo;

  f1(foo);
  f2(foo); // error: reference initialization is ambiguous
}
```

of course, this doesn't apply to the `vector<>` case (unless the test machinery passes some kind of 'tester' object with a broken (maybe templated, sfinae-unfriendly-whatever) converting operator to some wrapped vector member ? seems unreasonable ... but not impossible)

Comment: Interesting... Actually this is only possible due to bad const-ness (should normally have been `operator NTC const&() const;`) -- and actually not the function call is causing the problem, but the assignment to the parameter (same problem whenever assigning foo to an ordinary reference variable...). Still, valid example, congratulations...

Comment: @Aconcagua yep that’s  a pretty insane example; a more reasonable example might be a failing templated operator T&&()...

Comment: Outch, this is _nasty_! This answers my question (I'll accept it soon), and tends to confirm there is nothing fundamentally wrong to add this `const` qualifyer as I did. Thank you.

Comment: See my comment on the question giving the bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

If there was such an expression (apart from such cases where `f2` was inaccessible for any reason), that would break my own C++ knowledge entirely...

I consider it much more likely that you implemented a minimal bug (you are not yet aware of) in your function leading to failure; cannot exclude, though, that the test evaluation software is dumb enough just to look for a fix, given signature, no matter if yours is compatible or not...

Comment: You confirm my suspicion... and i'm yet to dig (again) into those paths (bug from my end or bug from theirs). I'm still hoping to learn something here.

Comment: I'd like to, but I've been asked not to share it outside my company. Some more experienced dev than me are looking at it currently.

Comment: See my comment on the question giving the bottom line.